# adding a jQuery event in the initialize but getting an error

Tags: jquery, backbone.js

I'm migrating some things to backbone and have a question about this error

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object loadPrevious has no method 'apply'
```

for this code:

```
el: $('#mig-container'),
events: {'click .next-btn' : 'loadNext' },
 template:_.template($('#mig-image-tmp').text()),
initialize: function() {
     $('#mig-container').on('click','.prev-btn',this.loadPrevious());
},....
loadPrevious: function(){
  console.log('i want to load Previous');
}
```

How would I make this on click event handler work properly?

thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it should be

```
$('#mig-container').on('click','.prev-btn',this.loadPrevious);
```

you should not invoke the event handler in event registration by appending `()` to the end of `loadPrevious`, you need to pass the function reference to `.on()`